# How can I rename the columns in Numbers?

Tags: macos, numbers

I'm working with a language file, with columns for different languages. My first row is the language names.

[image: languages]

Is it possible to have the "A", "B", "C", etc as language names instead. That way, when I scroll I can still identify each column.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As often happens, a couple of minutes after posting the question, I found a way to do this.

In the **Inspector**, (opt-cmd-i), in the **Table Inspector** tab click on the middle button of **Headers and Footers**. Select the option **Freeze Header Rows** and the first row will stick to the top.

[image]

Comment: Nice solution! Which software do you use to take screenshots like that btw?

Comment: Thanks! I used the wonderful Skitch http://www.skitch.com/

Comment: Fantastic. Made my day (I'm traveling so it's easy to do).

Comment: @Richard good to hear!

Answer (score 5):

I would think it would be better to *freeze* the first row and by so, it will be visible all over the document when you scroll. But unfortunately, this function <s>isn't</s> wasn't available in Numbers.

You might try editing the document in **Print View**. The columns and rows are repeated as you scroll, which allows you to see what column/row you are on. Numbers does allow editing in print view. It's not exactly what you are looking for, but it's a solution.

**Edit:** And as you've answered your own question, it looks like this function is available at this moment.

Comment: I sure wish numbers had this, I can't believe it doesn't. I've been looking for it for a while now and gave up. Freezing or locking a row or column is incredible important and should be in every spreadsheet program. It's in the program Tables for what it's worth.

Comment: @Michiel Thanks for the answer. I actually found the option to freeze header rows a couple of minutes after I posted the question. The option to freeze header rows is a little hidden away. It's in the Inspector.

Comment: Cool, didn't knew that :-) Great!